# Can I interchange hot and neutral wires on a Shelly 1 AC input?

Tags: mains, wiring

Shelly 1 can be powered by 110-240 VAC. I will use ti as a temperature sensor and I need to power my device from a regular European socket, which means that the user can plug into the wall in any direction, meaning that L and N might interchange.

I haven't found any mention in the [Shelly 1 documentation](https://shelly.cloud/knowledge-base/devices/shelly-1/) to specifically do or don't do this. I assume at this point that I should **not** do it.

However, I'd be interested if anyone had experiences with this setup that might be common?

[image: wiring]

Comment: The device knows no difference between active and neutral. It might only be an issue when switching power to another device as only the active is switched. This might create safety issues if the input was swapped.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Shelly support with this particular question and they responded kindly and quickly:

> It is absolutely okay for the L and N to be interchangeable as shown
> in your connection diagram.
>
> Shelly Support Team